# getting error in for each loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, watin

I am using for each loop in c#. While using for each I am getting error like this

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

This is my code:

```
foreach (Element e in browserInstance.Span(Find.ByClass("")))
{
    PropertyFeatures += e.OuterText.Trim() + ";";

    if (e.OuterText.Contains("Number of Bedrooms"))
        NoOfBedRooms = Utility.GetNumber(e.OuterText);
    else if (e.OuterText.Contains("Number of Bathrooms"))
        NoOfBathRooms = Utility.GetNumber(e.OuterText);
    else if (e.OuterText.Contains("Floor no. of Property"))
        FloorNoOfProperty = Utility.GetNumber(e.OuterText);
    else if (e.OuterText.Contains("Number of Floors"))
        NumberOfFloors = Utility.GetNumber(e.OuterText);
    else if (e.OuterText.Contains("Number of Lifts"))
        NumberOfLifts = Utility.GetNumber(e.OuterText);
}
```

Comment: I don't know watin, but you might try a property of method of result of the `.Span()`   like: `browserInstance.Span(Find.ByClass("")).Content` / `browserInstance.Span(Find.ByClass("")).Children`, because the `.Span()` doesn't seem to return a collection.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `browserInstance.Spans()` (Note the pluralising **s**)

Comment: if i give spans means.then also it shows error

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that `browserInstance.Span()` is not returning a type that implements `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score -1):

In this context the Element type should implement an interface, IEnumerable and implement GetEnumerator() method inside that type. Then this error will vanish...